# Working in dataframe, I want to manipulate column values based on values in another column

Tags: r

Working in dataframe, I want to manipulate column values based on values in another column. Here is my reproducible code:

```
# four items
items <- c("coke", "tea", "shampoo","aspirin")

# scores for each item
score <- as.numeric(c(65,30,45,20))

# making a data frame of the two vectors created
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(items,score))

# score for coke is 65 and for tea it is 30.  I want to
# double score for tea OR coke if the score is below 50

ifelse(df$score[df$items %in% c("coke", "tea")] < 50, df$score*2, df$score)

#the above return NULL values with warning

#the statement df$score[df$items %in% c("coke", "tea")] does pull coke and tea scores

df$score[df$items %in% c("coke", "tea")]
```

many thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. A [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) would be helpful

Comment: #four itmes
items <- c("coke", "tea", "shampoo","aspirin")

# scores for each item
score <- as.numeric(c(65,30,45,20))

#making a data frame of the two vectors created
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(items,score))

#score for coke is 65 and for tea it is 30.  I want to double score for tea OR #coke if the score is below 50

ifelse(df$score[df$items %in% c("coke", "tea")] < 50, df$score*2, df$score)

Comment: Please edit the formatting of your question!

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick for now:

```
items <- c("coke", "tea", "shampoo","aspirin")

# scores for each item
score <- as.numeric(c(65,30,45,20))
```

Try using `data.frame` instead of `as.data.frame`. Using the latter causes the values to be converted to factors

```
# making a data frame of the two vectors created
df <- data.frame(items, score)

df
    items score
1    coke    65
2     tea    30
3 shampoo    45
4 aspirin    20


# score for coke is 65 and for tea it is 30.  I want to
# double score for tea OR coke if the score is below 50

df$score[df$items %in% c("coke", "tea")] = ifelse(df$score[df$items %in% c("coke", "tea")] < 50, df$score*2, df$score)

df
    items score
1    coke    65
2     tea    60
3 shampoo    45
4 aspirin    20
```

This method doesn't work if you end up having duplicate entries for for items though.

```
# New data with an added entry for item = coke and score = 15:
items <- c("coke", "tea", "shampoo","aspirin","coke")
# scores for each item
score <- c(65,30,45,20,15)

# making a data frame of the two vectors created
df <- data.frame(items, score)


# using the method from above the last entry get converted to a value of 90
# instead of 30
df$score[df$items %in% c("coke", "tea")] = ifelse(df$score[df$items %in% c("coke", "tea")] < 50, df$score*2, df$score)

df
    items score
1    coke    65
2     tea    60
3 shampoo    45
4 aspirin    20
5    coke    90
```

So if you have any cases where you may have duplicate entries you will have to use this method

```
df <- data.frame(items, score)

df$score[df$items %in% c("coke", "tea") & df$score < 50] <- 2* df$score[df$items %in% c("coke", "tea") & df$score < 50]

df
    items score
1    coke    65
2     tea    60
3 shampoo    45
4 aspirin    20
5    coke    30
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem does not need an if statement.  You can just combine two logical statements.

Logical 1: `df$items %in% c("coke", "tea")`

Logical 2: `df$score < 50`

By filtering the dataframe on these two logical statements you can multiply the score. and= `&`, or= `|`.

`df$score[df$items %in% c("coke", "tea") | df$score < 50] <- 2* df$score[df$items %in% c("coke", "tea") | df$score < 50]`

Comment: hi Polka,  the first logical evaluates as expected but the second one results in NULL value for all four.  > df$score < 50
[1] NA NA NA NA     probably thats why i am getting error.  it is strage that df$score gives me all the vector but df$score < 50 results in four NA values

Comment: Thanks polka!!!   it did work.  Though score vector the way I created is a factor that caused df$score < 50 to result in NA NA NA NA.  I got it working following your suggestion.  THANK YOU!

Comment: I am one upvote away from being able to turn off ads.  If my answer worked, would you please upvote my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
items <- c("coke", "tea", "shampoo","aspirin")
score <- as.numeric(c(65,30,45,20))
```

If you call data.frame() in the following way you avoid converting the score column to a factor.

```
df <- data.frame(items=items,score=score)
```

You don't need an if statement. You can simply extract the values you are interested in based on two logical statements:

```
df[df$score<50 & df$items %in% c("coke", "tea"), "score"] <- 2 * df[df$score<50 & df$items %in% c("coke", "tea"), "score"]
```

---

- `df$score<50 & df$items %in% c("coke", "tea")` selects the rows that match both conditions, i.e. item either coke or tea and score less than 50.
- `"score"` selects only the score column
- The statement on the right of `<-` extracts the same value(s) and multiplies them by 2.

Comment: thanks Tom.  Your solution                                                                    df[df$score<50 & df$items %in% c("coke", "tea"), "score"] <- 2 * df[df$score<50 & df$items %in% c("coke", "tea"), "score"]                                   does make sense but it gives me an error                                                    df[df$score<50 & df$items %in% c("coke", "tea"), "score"]                             results in [1] <NA> <NA>

Comment: Try creating again the df data.frame with the line that I suggested above (`df <- data.frame(items=items,score=score)`).

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for your if statement is not quite correct, it looks like you're trying to invoke it in a way similar to how it is used in MS Excel. Unfortunately, it's not doing the trick.

I would suggest you take an intro to R course (many are available for free online), such as:

https://campus.datacamp.com/courses/free-introduction-to-r/chapter-1-intro-to-basics-1?ex=1

As for your problem, here is one solution (if i am understanding your problem correctly).

```
item <- c("coke", "tea", "shampoo", "aspirin")
score <- as.numeric(c(65, 30, 45, 20))

df <- data.frame(item, score)

for (i in 1:length(df$item)){
  if ((df$item[i] == "coke" | df$item[i] == "tea") & df$score[i] < 50) {
    df$score[i] <- df$score[i] * 2
  }
}

View(df)
```

You'll note that if you now view the updated dataframe ("df"), only the score for item "tea" has been doubled, since it meets both criteria (i.e. item = coke OR tea; AND it's associated score is below 50).

Hope this helps, and good luck.

Comment: thanks Element89.  I am a new to R and will look into the link you sent.  Your code reads perfectly fine but i get an error when i cut paste into r.  here is the error that i get...     Error in if ((df$item[i] == "coke" | df$item[i] == "tea") & df$score[i] <  : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning message:
In Ops.factor(df$score[i], 50) : < not meaningful for factors

Comment: Although this works, in general I would recommend avoiding the for loop in favour of vectorisation/subscripting. Circle 3 of the _R Inferno_  by Patrick Burns is a very interesting read (http://www.burns-stat.com).

Comment: Hey, looked into that! Thanks Tom!

Comment: @seakyourpeak odd, I just re-copied and pasted the code into a blank script and i did not get the error you're describing? I think it's OK, it should do what you want, but as Tom said, there are more elegant ways of getting the same result.